# In php, how to set a define-d value in a const?

Tags: php

Lets say in the very first script, which always executes first, I defined something:

```
define ('ROOTDIR', dirname(__FILE__));
define ('ROOTDIR_ASSETS', ROOTDIR.'/assets');
```

now a class:

```
class PictureGallery
{
    const PATH = ROOTDIR.'/imgs';
```

php say: syntax error, unexpected '.' expecting ' ' or ';'.
How to work it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have a class constant defined with string concatenation.

You'll need to use a member variable. If you don't want this changed, I would suggest making it private and only creating a getter to access it.

```
class PictureGallery
{
  private $_path;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_path = ROOTDIR.'/imgs';
  }
  public function getPath()
  {
    return $this->_path;
  }
}
```

OR

You could also calculate the value before defining the class, however this is a messy solution.

```
define('IMGDIR', ROOTDIR.'/imgs');
class PictureGallery 
{
  const PATH = IMGDIR;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Class constants is PHP must be a constant expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). So you either have to create another `define`d constant with the full path or you have to inject the path into the constructor of the class. Or just set in in the constructor.